# Why is returning null value?

Tags: android, class

I have set the EditBox variables in Main class. I want to get the value of the editbox in another class. But return a null value. Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
public class Main extends Activity{ 
{
EditText name; 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
loadInfo(); }

loadInfo()
{
SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        name.setText(preferences.getString("name", ""));
}  

}


public class A
{
 Main m;

String str= m.name.getText().toString(); 
}
```

Comment: The code that you posted will not compile because it is completely invalid. Please post your actual code, or a compilable example that fully demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You never instantiate m; you merely create a reference for type `Main`, and call it `m`.  You have to use:

```
Main m = new Main();
```

Comment: He never instantiates `name` in the `Main` class, either, for that matter (although the syntax is completely invalid anyway; the example won't compile).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) if you want pass string from Activity to Activity.

Answer (score 0):

inside the activity, `name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);`

To use the "name"(which is an odd name for an EditText, BTW) inside other classes, you need to have a reference to the Main instance, and you can do this: `mainInstance.name`.

Although I think it's not a good idea to keep "name" public.
In many places, you can use: `findViewById()` to get the View, `View.getContext(), Adapter.getContext()` to get the context, which is the Main instance.(You need to cast if you want to use your own methods.)

I didn't test, but I think you can not instantiate Main in android like this `new Main()`.

Anyway, I suggest you read some basic Android tutorials :)